# Can I use npm packges in a vanilla web page?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-live-server

I have a simple web page made up of vanilla html, css and js files.

I'd like to be able to use the `import { moment } from "moment"` syntax in my js files but when I add npm to my proejct, install moment wiht `npm install` and use that syntax when I run my app using live-server I get an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "moment". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Comment: Note that the Moment library is on life support, and they recommend checking out Luxon or Day as modern alternatives.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you have to configure the server accordingly.

Comment: @Pointy yes good point. I should have mentioned that I chose moment purely because I knew I could test the import with a very simple `let x = new moment()`, not because I cared about the package itself

Comment: If you still don't know, how to achieve it, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules. It describes it. This question contains example code for `moment`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70902863/whats-script-type-importmap-used-for

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Browsers support native ES6 modules for more than 6 years. Here is an example configuration for Express, but it should work with all serious web servers.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "moment": "/moment"
      }
    }
  </script>

  <script type="module" src="/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Moment</h1>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`app.js`:

```
import moment from 'moment';
let x = new moment();
document.querySelector('div').textContent = x;
```

`index.js`:

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
import { dirname } from 'node:path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/app.js', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app.js');
});

app.get('/moment', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/node_modules/moment/dist/moment.js');
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Server running...');
});
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21"
  }
}
```

I've used an import map to allow `import moment from 'moment';` without relative paths. You have to configure your web server to point to the Moment JavaScript code.

If the web server doesn't support a rewrite (as I used for Moment), you have to use the full path in the import map.

Here you can find out more about native ES6 modules: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was hoping to find a way to have non-relative imports without having to set up an importmap, as that essentially just moves the relative import to another location. I think I've found a soluiont using webpack that does what I want, I'll update this question if I get it working.

Comment: @user14216042 You shouldn't change the question after it was answered. Your question is how to do this without build systems like Webpack. Don't invalidate given answers.

Comment: @user14216042 You shouldn't change the question after it was answered. Your question is how to do this without build systems like Webpack. Don't invalidate given answers. I wouldn't recommend asking basic questions about bundling or Webpack. There are dozens of duplicates. In addition, I wouldn't recommend using Webpack for new projects. It was a great tool 5 years ago, but today it's considered slow and complex. A modern alternative is Vite.